# Line Break between two radio buttons

Tags: html, jsf-2

I have below code in JSF 2.0

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{StageGate.sketchesSG002006Decision}" onclick="validateMyRadioButton()" id="radio26">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Accepted" itemLabel="Accepted" id="accepted"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Rejected" itemLabel="Rejected" id="rejected"/>
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

I got output as

0 Accepted  0 Rejected

But i want output like

0 Accepted

0 Rejected

Answer (score 6):

You only need to add this attribute to your tag :

```
layout="pageDirection"
```

**More info :**

- [JSF 2.0 h:selectOneRadio](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html)

---

If you need a custom layout (say for example integrate radio buttons inside a custom table), you should use the `t:selectOneRadio`.

**More info :**

- [Apache MyFaces Tomahawk t:selectOneRadio](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html)

Comment: say suppose if i want dis radio buttons in proper alignment means what should i do?